# mongoose mpromise onResolve called before then

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In my code below, the onResolve() function is called after the first then function before any others (see it when req.body.length > 1). Any idea why? I want to add the saved asset lists to the array and then send that array in the response after all the findOneAndUpdate executions finish.

```
exports.saveAssetLists = function(req, res) {
  console.log('starting save asset lists');
  if (!Common.testIfValidForSave(req.body, true)) {
    res.status(400).send({error:'Invalid request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req)});
    return;
  }

  var deferred = null;
  var savedAssetLists = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
    var newAssetList = new AssetList(req.body);
    var d = AssetList.findOneAndUpdate({_id: newAssetList._id }, newAssetList, {upsert:true, new:true}).exec().then(function(obj) {
      console.log('then - obj: ' + JSON.stringify(obj));
        savedAssetLists.push(obj);
    });
    if (!deferred) {
      deferred = d;
    } else {
      deferred.chain(d);
    }
  }
  deferred.onResolve(function(err, result) {
    console.log('onResolve - err: ' + err + ', result: ' + result + ', savedAssetLists: ' + savedAssetLists);
    res.send({data: savedAssetLists});
  })
  .onReject(function(err) {
    res.status(500).send({error: err});
  });
  return deferred;
};
```

This is the log output:

```
starting save asset lists
then - obj: {"_id":"561eafe95c0df2c0468cb798","name":"Asset List 1","__v":0,"assets":[null]}
onResolve - err: null, result: undefined, savedAssetLists: { _id: 561eafe95c0df2c0468cb798,
  name: 'Asset List 1',
  __v: 0,
  assets: [ null ] }
then - obj: {"_id":"561eafe95c0df2c0468cb799","name":"Asset List 2","__v":0,"assets":[null]}
```

As per a suggestion from Vsevolod, I changed my code to the below, but the then method never gets called:

```
exports.saveAssetLists = function(req, res) {
  console.log('starting save asset lists');
  if (!Common.testIfValidForSave(req.body, true)) {
    res.status(400).send({error:'Invalid request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req)});
    return;
  }

  var promises = [];
  var savedAssetLists = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {
    var newAssetList = new AssetList(req.body[i]);
    var p = AssetList.findOneAndUpdate({_id: newAssetList._id }, newAssetList, {upsert:true, new:true}).exec();
    promises.push(p);

  }
  Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
    console.log('onResolve - err: ' + err + ', values: ' + values + ', savedAssetLists: ' + savedAssetLists);
    res.send({data: values });
  }, function(err) {
    res.status(500).send({error: err});
  });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need such a complex call if you can use just get a bunch of promises, push them to `Promise.all` and get results inside it?

Comment: good question. mongoose.Promise.all() doesn't exist according to my console

Comment: It's not `mongoose.Promise.all` it's just `Promise.all`. I'll make an answer

Comment: not supported apparently? https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create an array of promises out of your `req.body`:

```
var promises = req.body.map(function(data){
    var newAssetList = new AssetList(data);
    return AssetList.findOneAndUpdate({_id: newAssetList._id }, newAssetList, {upsert:true, new:true})
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
   return res.send({data: results});
}).catch(function(err){
    return res.status(500).send({error: err});
});
```

A small note: don't require `mpromise` library in your code. This should work for mongoose 4+

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I did something almost identical (almost) and the then function never gets called (see my edit above)

Comment: You don't need to call `exec` as the `findOneAndUpdate` return a promise. Try my code

Comment: Thank you! your code worked! Although I don't understand why mine didn't even after I removed the .exec() statement

Comment: It's hard to say why is that, glad that the code worked!